# How to set Instantiated GameObject`s `RectTransform`.Left & Right in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

I want to instantiate `clue_prefabs` inside my `Clues`. Help me to set the instantiated clue_prefab's `left` and `right` and set the position `y` to 497 -150 for each instantiated clue_prefab.

```
GameObject new_clue_prefab = Instantiate(cluePrefab, new Vector3(360, 1000 - (i * 130)),
                                           Quaternion.identity, clueContainer);
```

This code has the output of left: 133, right:133

[image: screenshot of behavior]

Comment: Ok good, you have code, and a screenshot. However I am not sure what the *problem* is. That is: what is this code doing that you want to be different?